# Set array element to null with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I'm encountering an interesting problem, trying to set to null an element of a sub-array in mongo with mongoose (wich seems ridiculously obvious, yep).

My Schema looks like :

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  name : String,
  slots: { type: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Slot' }], default: [] }
});
```

My data looks like :

```
{
  _id  : ObjectId("53bafbfd00cbcc3a1178e11b"),
  name : "item 1",
  slots: [null, null, ObjectId("53baf297d63228631029d2f8"), null, null]
},
{
  _id  : ObjectId("53baf297d63228631029d2f8"),
  name : "item 2",
  slots: [ObjectId("53baf1b3fecfe25c10233801"), null, null, null, null]
}
```

nb: the `null`values are important for order logical purposes.

So, let's imagine I get the first of these items :

```
Items.findById('53bafbfd00cbcc3a1178e11b', function (err, item) {

  console.log(item.slots);
  // [null, null, "53baf297d63228631029d2f8", null, null] --> OK

  // BIG update here
  item.slots[2] = null;

  item.save(function (err, itemSaved) {

    // no errors

    console.log(itemSaved.slots);
    // [null, null, null, null, null] --> Well, so everything works, right ?

    // so let's find the same item again !

    Items.findById('53bafbfd00cbcc3a1178e11b', function (err, itemSearched) {

      console.log(itemSearched.slots);
      // [null, null, "53baf297d63228631029d2f8", null, null] --> what ?? id still here ?

    });

  });

});
```

So the id isn't set to `null` even if `save` worked.. I don't get it, really. I need so much an explanation ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try console.logging `item.save(function (err, itemSaved) {` the itemSaved ?

Comment: I updated my question in this way : saved item looks ok, but not after the last Find query..

Comment: How is `slots` defined in your schema?

Comment: I updated my question, so you can now see my Schema

Comment: Have you checked within mongo to see if the value is actually updated or not?

Comment: I did, and value is not updated.

Comment: I ran into this a while ago, actually. `item.save` sometimes does not call update on changed values properly, if you actually step through using a debugger, you will see interesting stuffs.

Comment: Best way to do it is to utilize mongo `update` which will probably work. Just make a wrapper method around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to explicitly mark that element as modified or `save` won't pick up the change:

```
item.slots[2] = null;
item.markModified('slots.2');
item.save(function (err, itemSaved) {
    ....
```

Perhaps because `null` is not a valid `ObjectId`.

The other way to do this is with `update` and `$unset`:

```
Items.update(
    {_id: '53bafbfd00cbcc3a1178e11b'},
    {$unset: {'slots.2': 1}}, function(err, numAffected) {
        ...
```

Comment: Good solution, you can also just do `item.markModified('slots')` right?

Comment: @tpae That also works, but it's not as efficient as Mongoose then has to update the whole array instead of just the modified element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
Items.update(
    {_id: '53bafbfd00cbcc3a1178e11b'}, 
    {$set: { slots: [null, null, null, null, null] } }, 
function(err, results) {
  Items.findById('53bafbfd00cbcc3a1178e11b', function (err, itemSearched) {
      console.log(itemSearched.slots);
    });
  });
});
```

Make a wrapper function around it, like this:

```
ItemSchema.statics.clearSlot = function(id, slot, cb) {
  var self = this;
  this.findById(id, function(err, item) {
    var slots = item.slots;
    slots[slot] = null;
    self.update({_id: id}, {$set: {slots: slots}}, cb);
  });
});
```

Something like that. lol

Call it like

`Item.clearSlot(id, 2, function(err, updated) {`

Comment: Sry, but it's not exactly what I search. I need to set one element of the 'slots' array to `null`, not to reset it to its blank state (not sure if I explain well ^^)